# Multi-hop reverse SSH tunneling with two clients

Tags: linux, networking, firefox, ssh, putty

a). I have the Remote client 1 (raspberry pi) which is behind a router1 connected to the Internet with no port forwarding.

b). I have a SSH server with known IP.

c). I have my laptop on which I want to use a proxy in Firefox to login on router1.

I tried to do like this:

On Remote client 1 (raspberry pi) I do this:

```
ssh -N -R 2222:localhost:22 root@66.77.88.99
```

On my laptop i ssh into the server

```
ssh root@66.77.88.99
```

And do this

```
ssh -l root -p 2222 localhost
```

In order to ssh in remote client 1

3.I set the putty tunnels like this

[image: putty tunnels]

and Firefox like this

[image: Firefox settings]

And now if I'm going to myipaddress. I'll have the server ip address and NOT the Remote client1 ip address.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is very different from the way I do this, and I do not think your way is correct.

1. First, you need to setup a SOCK5 proxy on your RPI, which I do not believe you have done so far.

   ```
   ssh -fN -D 50000 localhost
   ```

   This opens port 50000 as a SOCK5 proxy. The option *-f* puts the process in the background, which is useful because you need to give another command on the RPI. But it also requires that you have setup passwordless login on the RPI, which is in general such an important thing that I strongly urge you  to do it irrespective of what we are discussing here.
2. Now you need to forward some port (let's say 6666) from the remote server to the RPI SOCK5 proxy:

   ```
   ssh -fN me@server -R 6666:localhost:50000
   ```
3. Now you need to forward a port local to your laptop to your remote server. If this were a Linux/Unix machine, the command would be:

   ```
   ssh -fN me@server -L 8000:localhost:6666
   ```

   Unfortunately, I never use Windows so I cannot suggest how to do this in Putty, but you seem knowledgeable enough to work it out without my help.
4. And lastly, you may now configure your browser to use as a SOCK5 proxy *localhost:8000*.

Please notice that none of this concerns forwarding the normal ssh ports, 22 or 2222, which appears to be what you have done. The ports to be forwarded are **other than** the ssh ports. In fact, these ports are *not even* opened on your outward-facing interface, they are opened on your local (*lo* = 127.0.0.1) interface, which is why you do not need to alter your firewall configuration to make this work. And this, in turn is why you can get around the restrictive firewall configuration of your RPI LAN. All traffic, even that intended for ports 6666,50000, or 8000, is routed thru the ssh ports (22, or perhaps 2222 in the case of your router), and then it is correctly routed by ssh to *localhost:6666/50000/8000* inside the destination pc.

Also, there is a disconnection between the proxy  port in Firefox (port 2012 for you) and the server port being forwarded to the RPI, which is 2222: these two ports need to be the same: as you see in my example, on the server I **always** use port 6666, so that proxy-related packets flow from the laptop to the server:6666, and then from the server:6666 to the RPI:50000. But in the end, none of this matters in your case because you do not have a SOCK5 proxy listening on the RPI, which instead you should have setup.

And, BTW, if you plan on leaving the connection between RPI and server unattended for long periods of time, like hours or days as you travel with your laptop, you may perhaps look at [autossh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh), a highly convenient script which checks that the ssh connections are open, and if not it kills the previous ssh connection and starts it afresh automatically. This way you are guaranteed to find the connection from the server to the RPI always on, even if you are travelling for days on end.

It works, I just tried it over a connection spanning a couple of oceans  ;-)

Comment: Hi Marius,

Thanks for all the help!

Your idea sounds very good, I've tried and it works partially on my side.

The connection from RPI to server it's done by reverse ssh, so i think i must send some other ssh commands in order to "bind" the RPI to the server.

I've tried like this on RPI terminal `ssh -N -R 50000:localhost:50000 me@server`

Comment: Doing this im not sure if it's the right way
What do you think ?

Comment: Also, if im not doing that command i'll get `connect_to localhost port 50000: failed` in server terminal

Comment: @John The command looks Ok, you just dropped the option *-f* which means you can login via password. It will fail if you have **not** setup a connection profile in *~/.ssh/config*, which now I presume you have not done. If you did, you would not need to pass any other option on the CLI, but, strictly speaking you do **not have to** do it. Also, you are using the same number for the port on both RPI and server. Nothing wrong with it, but using two different ports makes debugging easier.

Comment: So far so good, i will add some details regarding my setup:  

The RPI it's conected to internet by wlan0 (to router1) and it's sharing  it's internet to eth0 (static ip) to another router2.  
router1 ip: 192.168.1.1  
wlan0   ip: 192.168.1.150  
eth0    ip: 192.168.100.1  
router2 ip: 192.168.100.4  

At this point i'm able to reach the router1 config page, but if i go to router2 i receive (RPI console):  

channel 5: open failed: connect failed: No route to host  
channel 6: open failed: connect failed: No route to host

Comment: channel 8: open failed: connect failed: No route to host
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: No route to host.  


I cannot figure what's the problem, the internet it's working in router2, also i can acces router2 from a PC connected to router1.

Comment: I'm very sorry for the text formating, but i cannot get it work by adding two spaces to create a new line

Comment: @John What does this have to do with your OP? I am confused.